# Explanation of Storage compression options in OrientDB needed

Tags: java, orientdb

I cannot find any documentation about the Storage compression options in OrientDB. Looking at the source code [master/1.7.7] i have found this:

- OGlobalConfiguration#STORAGE_COMPRESSION_METHOD: "Record compression method is used in storage. Possible values : gzip, nothing, snappy, snappy-native. Default is snappy."
- Implementations in package com.orientechnologies.orient.core.compression.impl:

  - nothing
  - zerocopy   // same array is returned if offset == 0 and length == content.length (so optimized nothing)
  - gzip
  - low-zip    why zip, strange format if you already have gzip
  - high-zip
  - snappy
- When using OSGi snappy does not work?

So this is far from consistent. Besides this, what is de gain in performance when using snappy? Is there any benchmark? H2 database uses LZF algorithm and disables this by default (with a reason).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compression is done at record level. After many user reports about compression statistics, we decided for OrientDB 2.0 (now in alpha) to switch the default implementation to "nothing" because the gain in space is pretty rare and only with big records.

So if you are using any version before 2.0, I suggest you to create the database without such compression by executing the OrientDB console with this setting (edit last line console.sh adding this):

```
-Dstorage.compressionMethod=nothing
```

Comment: That makes sense and is more in line with my experience. I would suggest using compression only at field/property level for specific data types (text and binary), this also should be optional.